# Twitter Bootstrap Tabs Jump

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

ok I search the forum before posting here & found many solution. unfortunately not a single one is working for me. I'm using latest bootsrap v3.3.5 & when ever I try to change my tabs the page jump to top & the content from the tab panel goes down.

```
<div id="featured-tabs">
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="list-inline" role="tablist">
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#residential" aria-controls="residential" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-theme-primary btn-lg">Residential</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#commercial" aria-controls="commercial" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-theme-secondary btn-lg">Commercial</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="residential">
....content here
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="commercial">
....content here
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

& here is my js:

```
$('#featured-tabs ul.list-inline li a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
        history.pushState( null, null, $(this).attr('href') );
    })
```

so how I can solve this page jump problem for latest Bootstrap version?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have jquery and bootstrap.js files before closing bod tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You can use it without javascript as it says in bootstrap
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

just:

```
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

here demo http://jsbin.com/vafetewawe/edit?html,output

Comment: ok cool, thanks for the info. but it did not solve my jumping problem.

Comment: check if you have included jquery - without jquery bootstrap js won't work

Comment: yes I include jQuery, otherwise revolution slider would not work.

Comment: added demo link http://jsbin.com/vafetewawe/edit?html,output
not sure why it goes up for you, but it doesn't in the demo for sure

Comment: ok I've uploaded to one of my friends server. banglapdf.net/Zinx

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$('#featured-tabs ul.list-inline li a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $(this).tab('show');
        history.pushState( null, null, $(this).attr('href') );
})
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: at the bottom orange buttons. Residential & Commercial